# VBA Shapes.AddTextbox customize layout

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, formatting, format

I want a text box in Excel using VBA looking like this:

[image: example of ideal text box]

- Text in the Test Box in RGB(0,112,192) (blue)
- Shape outline of the text box in RGB (0,112,192).
- Weight of the lines in '1 1/2'.

I already created this code but I don't know how to program this.

---

```
Sub TextBox()

Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
myDocument.Shapes.AddTextBox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    100, 100, 200, 50) _
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Test Box of how I would like it"
      
End Sub
```

---

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Turn on the macro recorder. Insert a text box. Format it. Turn off the macro recorder. Look at the code. You need to clean it up some, but it will have all the commands you need.

Answer (score 1):

After defining the variables and coding, it helps to write the code.

```
Sub TextBox()
    Dim myDocument As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim s As String

    Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
    Set Shp = myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 200, 50)
    With Shp
        With .TextFrame
            s = "Test Box of how I would like it"
            .Characters.Text = s
            .Characters(1, Len(s)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 112, 193)
        End With
        .Line.Weight = 1.5
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 193)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the macro recorder while setting the line width, line color and text colour, you will find the code to do that.

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Weight = 1.5
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).Font.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
```

Comment: It gives error: Object doesnt support this property

`Sub TextBox()

Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
myDocument.Shapes.AddTextBox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    100, 100, 200, 50) _
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Test Box"

With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Weight = 2
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    .Transparency = 0
End With

With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).Font.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

End Sub

`

Comment: Please don't post code into comments. The code I posted works on a selected text box. You need to change it to apply to YOUR object. You need to make sure that YOUR object is addressed correctly. I cannot tell you what name or number your text box has. I just gave you what you need to change the colors, etc. Again: use the macro recorder. Select your object. Turn off the macro recorder. Look at the code. Do you get the principle??